# clean build/archive fails on xcode13

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode13, build-script, xcode-command-line-tools

trying to build or archive using clean command results in:

```
Could not delete some/build/path/here because it was not created by the build system and it is not a subfolder of derived data.
```

running the same without clean, works just fine. also, running the same on any older xcode will finish successfully.

running on macOS big sur, 11.6 Xcode Version 13.0 (13A233)

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to do it by selecting Destination as iPhone under the product option and then Product -> Archive instead of command line

Comment: that will work though its not what i need.